# Убить процесс в C#

Tags: c#, процесс

Я уже не знаю. Как я только не пробовал убить процесс chrome.exe через C#. Ничего не получается. Может кто то может подсказать, что не так с моим "кодом".

Сперва создаю массив всех процессов, потом обхожу этот массив и если имя процесса совпадает с нужной строкой - убиваю его.

```
Process[] listprosecc = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process oneproc in listprosecc)
{
    string ProsessName = oneproc.ProcessName;

    ProsessName = ProsessName.ToLower();
    if (ProsessName.Equals("chrome.exe"))
    {
        oneproc.Kill();
        MessageBox.Show("Я дошел!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: В `if` заходит?

Comment: `var pr = prss.Select(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("chrome")).Count();` у меня получается 141 штука таких процесса :)

Comment: @Ev_Hyper. Та в том и дело, что нет. Но процесс 100% имеет имя chrome.exe

Comment: @batya: А вы таки попробуйте `"chrome"`, без `.exe`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

А может так попробовать?

```
try
{
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте воспользоваться данным методом.

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("ваш процесс"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

не ставьте `.exe` в названии процесса.

Comment: Вот только что сам допер. Но все равно - спасибо.

Comment: @batya не совсем справедливо. Daniel Protopopov дал вам аналогичный ответ и даже раньше, но вы его почему-то не защитали.

Comment: @Bulson вы правы... но, не я выбирал)

Comment: @Insider а я к вам никаких претензий не имею, а обратился к `batya`

Comment: @Insider Все. Я поменял.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process[] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

foreach (Process p in chromeInstances)
    p.Kill();
```

Comment: Не подскажите, а какая разница между вашим решением и [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615040/217579)?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
Process[] chrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("Chrome");
chrome[0].Kill();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста старайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы, для этого надо нажать кнопку [edit].