# Как определить какой процесс использует нужный мне файл?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пишу приложение, использующее Selenium (ChromeDriver). При запуске, нужно удалить старые User Data, создать новые и запустить ПО уже на базе новых. Но если я недавно запускала своё приложение и закрыла его, то, подозреваю, ещё висят некоторые процессы, использующие старые User Data (хотя вызываю `driver.Dispose()` при закрытии). Этот процесс (-ы) не даёт мне некоторое время удалить старые User Data. Названия этого процесса не знаю, но подозреваю, что это `chrome.exe`. Но если kill все `chrome.exe`, то закроется и браузер, использующийся пользователем, а не только используемый Selenium-ом. Как определить какой процесс не даёт удалить нужный мне файл?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Убить процесс в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615032/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Для чего столько лишней информации если задача убить процесс, название которого и так известно?

Comment: @Andrew названия процесса не знаю. Просто знаю, что это процесс ChromeDriver'a. Допустим, это `chrome.exe` (но не факт). В списке запущенных процессов `chrome.exe` много и мне нужно знать какой именно использует нужный мне файл.

Comment: Попробуйте это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727180/240512

Comment: Голосующие за дубликат: вопрос, указанный в "возможный дубликат", совсем другой.